# Why ”find_one“ takes a longer time than ”find” in mongocxx（c++17）？

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, mongo-cxx-driver

I have a mongodb (about 5M，1.3W documents).

I use it with mongocxx (Visual Studio 2019, C++17), I compile the diver like this:

```
//mongoc release
cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=F:\mongo-windows-x64-cpp17\mongo-c-driver -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=F:\mongo-windows-x64-cpp17\mongo-c-driver -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

cmake --bulid . --config Release --target install

//mongocxx release
cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_STD=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS_WITH_STATIC_MONGOC=ON -DBUILD_VERSION=1.17.4 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/Zc:__cplusplus /EHsc" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=F:\mongo-windows-x64-cpp17\mongo-c-driver -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=F:\mongo-windows-x64-cpp17\mongo-cxx-driver -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBSONCXX_OUTPUT_BASENAME=bsoncxx -DMONGOCXX_OUTPUT_BASENAME=mongocxx ..

cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

Then I test time used by program as follows：

```c
#define KVP_CAST_DOUBLE(str, data) kvp((str), static_cast<double>(data))

mongocxx::instance mginstance{};

U32 _initial_mongodb()
{
    //client pool
    mongocxx::pool *p = new mongocxx::pool{ mongocxx::uri{ "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" } };

    //client
    std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::pool::entry> en = std::make_unique<mongocxx::pool::entry>(p->acquire());
    mongocxx::client& cli = *(*(en));

    //database
    auto mongo_db = cli["mongodb"];

    mongocxx::collection col = mongo_db["collection_knowledgedata"];


    //create index
    mongocxx::options::index unique_opts;
    unique_opts.unique(true);
    //SE_Knowledge
    col.create_index(make_document(kvp("id", 1)), unique_opts);
    col.create_index(make_document(kvp("id0", 1), kvp("id1", 1)), {});

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto result = col.find({});
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto delt1 = (t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << std::format("find all time = {} ns.\n", delt1);

    auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int i = 0;
    for (auto it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it)
    {
        ++i;
    }

    auto t4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto delt2 = (t4 - t3).count();
    std::cout << std::format("total documents = {}, loop time = {} ns.\n",i,  delt2);

    auto t5 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    bsoncxx::builder::basic::document doc;
    doc.append(KVP_CAST_DOUBLE("id", 40889));
    auto t6 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::format("make document time = {} ns.\n", (t6 - t5).count());

    auto t7 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto result2 = col.find_one(doc.view());
    auto t8 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::format("find one time = {} ns.\n", (t8 - t7).count());

    return EC_Success;
}
```

And the result is (release):

```
find all time = 13400 ns.
total documents = 13346, loop time = 13740400 ns.
make document time = 3200 ns.
find one time = 434400 ns.
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eNP2.png)

I find "find_one" takes more time than “find”...
I don't know why and how to optimize？
Thanks！

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose of this measurement. The query performance is measured using the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) method and this returns a _query plan_ document with details about usage of indexes for the query execution, the time taken, etc., by the query on the database server. When you run the explain method with your queries do specify the "executionStats" mode.

Comment: @prasad_ ,  the time in explain is millisecond, i want microsecond or nanosecond.

Comment: I don't know if you can get in micro / nano seconds in explain results. But, the way you are trying and getting the time is not accurate - it involves your query round-trip to the database server, includes network related delays, and factors like other load on your client and server, etc. The query optimization is achieved thru the process of studying query plans, creating indexes, etc. See [Query Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/). In general, applications aim at a little less than 100ms performance on the database side is considered good.

Comment: It doesn't really make much sense that iterating the documents in the local machine would take 1000x longer than fetching them from the remote server.  I suspect `find` only returned the first batch, and iterating caused the driver to request additional batches as needed.  i.e. the "find all time" should also include the "loop time" to be accurate.  Perhaps use `.ToList()` as part of the find call to make sure it has actually found all of the documents?